# manage QuerySelectField across Flask blueprints

Tags: flask

I have been through various tutorials + search on Stackoverflow / Google, but failed to find some answers on how to use QuerySelectField using several Flask blueprints, may be you could help.
Basically, I have defined a Project class and a Client class in my models.py as follows:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
   client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clients.id'))

class Client(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    projects = db.relationship('Project', lazy='dynamic', backref='project')
```

I then have a blueprint for each part, one to manage my projects, another one for my clients. 
I then get stuck when I try to use a QuerySelectField to retrieve the client names in my projects form, here is what I have so far in my projects/forms.py:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from wtforms.validators import Length, Required
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField


class ProjectForm(Form):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 128)])
    description = TextAreaField('Desciption')
    date = DateField('Date', format='%d/%m/%Y')
    client_id = QuerySelectField('Select Client', validators=[Required()], coerce=int, choices = [(1, 'abc'), (2, 'defg'), (3, 'hij')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def from_model(self, project):
        self.title.data = project.title
        self.description.data = project.description
        self.client_id.data = project.client_id
        self.date.data = project.date

    def to_model(self, project):
        project.title = self.title.data
        project.description = self.description.data
        project.client_id = self.client_id.data
        project.date = self.date.data
```

I know this version is NOT picking any client as I am passing static data i/o dynamic ones, but at least it works and I can see my SelectField with possible values. I have read I should be using something like

```
client_id = QuerySelectField('Select Client', query_factory=lambda: Client.query.all())
```

and been also recommended to first declare something like the following before "class ProjectForm(Form)":

```
def client_id():
    return Client.query.filter_by(enabled=True)
```

In all cases, I end up with a NameError: name 'Client' is not defined, I understand I have to say somewhere that the program should look at my class Client, but I failed finding where, unless the issue is somewhere else.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it simply this way:

```
def get_clients():
    from forms import Client
    return Client.query.all()
```

and then:

```
client_id = QuerySelectField('Select Client', query_factory=get_clients)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mehdi, I was mainly missing the 'from forms import Client' to make it run.